# Usar Cookie ou LocalStorage?

Tags: cookies, localstorage

Estava desenvolvendo um plugin para jQuery e precisei armazenar algumas informações.

Pensei em usar o `localStorage` do `HTML5`, porém fui alertado por um amigo que em algumas versões antigas de navegadores não funcionaria, e que eu deveria utilizar `Cookies`

Eu dei uma olhada no [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) para conferir isso, e lá diz o seguinte:

> Note: Internet Explorer 7 and earlier versions, do not support Web
>   Storage.

Ou seja:

> Internet Explorer 7 e versões anteriores, não suportam o Storage.

1. Devo realmente me preocupar ainda em desenvolver para o `Internet
   Explorer 7` ou versões anteriores?
2. Posso usar o localStorage seguro de que não vou ter problemas de
   compatibilidade com os browsers lançados nos meados de `Internet
   Explorer 9`, ou devo ainda usar o bom e velho `Cookie`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acho que isto depende bastante sobre o suporte que você pretende dar aos navegadores. Se você busca suportar a maior quantidade de navegadores possíveis você poderia utilizar, ou sugerir, um pollyfill para WebStorage.

No link segue uma lista de pollyfills disponiveis:

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Eu particularmente escolheria utilizar WebStorage, pois a tendência é de que os navegadores sejam atualizados com o passar dos anos e o IE 7 já é bastante antigo, apesar de ainda ser muito utilizado eu escolheria não dar suporte a ele.

Comment: Geralmente, nos sistemas que desenvolvo, me preocupo com o `IE 10` pra cima

Answer (score 2):

1. Devo realmente me preocupar ainda em desenvolver para o Internet
   Explorer 7 ou versões anteriores?

   Isso vai depender se você pretenderá dar suporte aos navegadores mais antigos, particularmente acredito que não seja necessário prestar suporte a navegadores com versões anteriores ao IE7, Firefox 3.5, até porque *não deve ter muitos utilizadores*, [**aqui**](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php) você pode ver algumas estatísticas sobre os navegadores mais utilizados.
2. Posso usar o `localStorage` seguro de que não vou ter problemas de compatibilidade com os browsers lançados nos meados de Internet Explorer 9, ou devo ainda usar o bom e velho `Cookie`?

   Você pode usar `localStorage` sem problemas em versões modernas, [**aqui**](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) você pode ver em quais navegadores ele é suportado.