# autenticação de paginas html

Tags: html, angularjs, autenticação

Trabalhava com WebForms em visual studio, porém agora vou trabalhar com HTML, css, javascript vou consumir um webservice com ajax, entao toda a programação será do lado do cliente nao havera programação no servidor. 
Minha dúvida é como fazer a autenticaçao das paginas depois de efetuado o login, li sobre SessionStorage(html5), localStorage(html5), cookies, angular js e mais outros que nao lembro agora. Qual a melhor opção ou uma opção que me dê segurança? Se tiverem algum exemplo agradeço muito.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48052/usar-cookie-ou-localstorage

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19384/diferen%C3%A7as-entre-localstorage-vs-sessionstorage

Comment: obrigado @LeoCaracciolo, porém como disse ja li sobre localstorage e sessionstorage, pelo que li do artigo ele é seguro, apenas nao funciona em browser antigos. Pela sua indicação vou usa-lo, vou abrir outro post para ver como implementa-lo antes de carregar a pagina para verificar se o usuario tem ou não permissao, obrigado!